# Decreasing sensitivity of a touch paddle

Tags: transistors, capacitance, ham-radio

I made a simple touch paddle using the circuit [here](https://m0ukd.com/homebrew/simple-cw-touch-keyer-circuits/). It is too sensitive and also triggers when my finger is only near one of the sides. How can I decrease sensitivity?

[image]

[image]

Comment: add <=10M to gnd on both Vbe

Comment: @TonyStewart works like a charm (with 1M). Thanks! Could you make that an answer?

Comment: Oops!  Didn't see that.  I had the question open to read, and didn't get around to it for a while. Tony posted his comment in the mean time, but the comments don't autoupdate on my phone.

Comment: @JRE no problem of course! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add <=10M to gnd on both Vbe
down to 1M.

Stray hum is needed to create the E field to trigger the transistor so in some conditions 1M may be too low. Your body acts as the antenna. The R shunts the E field picked up by your body. Somehow this triggers your circuit with (Non-retriggerable dit-dahs)

Beware to ground yourself before Mr. Morse's finger burns out your transistor from excess peak inverse Vbe.  a reverse clamp diode protects this greatly but not sure if that affects pulse trigger.